# How do I proof that for any set A there exists a set B whose elements are the power sets of the elements of A?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, set-theory, axioms

I wonder how to proof that:
"$B := \{ P(E) | E \in A \}$", using the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms and given the information in the Headline.

For example:

"$A = \{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$", thus "$B = \{ \{ \{ \emptyset, \{ a \} \}, \{ \emptyset, \{ b \}, \{ c \}, \{ b, c \}  \} \}$".

Using the axiom of power sets:
"$\forall x | x \in P \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq E $" with "$P$" being "$P(E)$" as well as "$E \in A$", how do I proof the existence of "$B$"?

I understand that using the axiom of power sets we suppose the existence of "$P(E)$" for any "$E \in A$". How can I now use atleast one of the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms to show that "$B$", containing every "$P(E)$" must exist? Does "$A$" simply containing more than one element force the collection of every "$P(E)$" to exist in a separate set? I guess no, but I can not explain.
Can someone please help me to understand which axiom should be used and why?

Thank you so much in advance, I am looking forward to your answer!

Comment: I would characterize $B$ as a subset of $P(P(\cup A))$ (the power set of the power set of the union of all elements of $A$), in particular $X\in B$ if there is $E\in A$ such that for every $Y$, $Y\in X$ if and only if $Y\subseteq E$

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks a lot, I read the answer and understood it!